# Why isn't IronPython setting my Control.Text correctly?

Tags: winforms, ironpython

I've been messing around with Python and IronPython this week and I've stumbled across an extremely annoying oddity.

Basically I am connecting to a MSSQL database and upon success setting `self.label1.Text = "Connected to " + sqlConn.Database + " on " + sqlConn.DataSource`, however my label is updating to just say "Connected to" on the form. I placed a `MessageBox.Show(self.label1.Text)` after and this displays all the correct information ("Connected to DATABASE on DATASOURCE"). My question is, why isn't IronPython setting my label text correctly on the form?

[image]

```
class MyForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.button1 = Button()
        self.button1.Text = "Click Me!"
        self.button1.Click += self.button1_Click
        self.Controls.Add(self.button1)

        self.label1 = Label()
        self.label1.Location = Point(10, 50)
        self.Controls.Add(self.label1)

    def button1_Click(self, sender, args):
        sqlConn = self.connectSql()
        if sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open:
            self.label1.Text = "Connected to " + sqlConn.Database + " on " + sqlConn.DataSource
            MessageBox.Show(self.label1.Text)
        else:
            self.label1.Text = "Failed connection"

    def connectSql(self):
        sqlConn = SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=IT_Project;Integrated Security=True;")
        try:
            sqlConn.Open()
        except System.Exception as ex:
            MessageBox.Show("Error!\r\n" + ex.Message, "EXCEPTION HANDLED")
        return sqlConn
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Are you sure that the label has the correct size and the content isn't just visually truncated?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I increased the size of the form and I can confirm the label text isn't being truncated off the form. I can write the same code in pure C# and it works fine.

Comment: Resizing of the form does not necessarily have any impact on the label's size. Could you try to set the [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize.aspx) property on the label to **true** to check if that changes anything? `self.label1.AutoSize = True` just after setting the location ..

Comment: `self.label1.AutoSize = True` fixed the issue! Thank you! I actually thought AutoSize was set to True by default? (At least it is in C#). Do you want to put that into an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Label.aspx) is truncated because of its default size and behavior. By manually setting a sufficient size or using the [AutoSize-Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize.aspx) the full content can be displayed.
The following code could be used after creating the label to size the label to its content:

```
self.label1.AutoSize = True
```

The fact that the message box displayed the full value from the actual control's text hinted to the underlying cause.

Note that according to the documentation the auto sizing default behavior may vary:

> When added to a form using the designer, the default value is true. When instantiated from code, the default value is false.

Comment: `When added to a form using the designer, the default value is true. When instantiated from code, the default value is false.` This I never knew. Thanks again.